# flutter : How to change the color of a single word in a sentence?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-test

### This is My text I want to change color which is in single quotes and last id, This text is dynamic Its coming from API ->

Your query 'THIS IS TESTING SUBJECT TRYING TO EXPLORE HAHA .' has been raised with ticket id: #0606c2a23d9e

I want to make like this
[image]

How to make it like this

Answer (score 1):

you can use RichText widget for this purpose in which you can give different styling to different part of the text

```
RichText(
 text: TextSpan(
 text: 'Hello ',
 style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
 children: const <TextSpan>[
  TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
  TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
],
),
)
```

Comment: But my text is dynamic , In single quotes text will be changed and last ID too

Comment: @Deepak in that case you might have to find some pattern in your text and apply styling according to that

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that we have a pattern with single quotes

```
Your query 'THIS IS TESTING SUBJECT TRYING TO EXPLORE HAHA .' has been raised with ticket id: #0606c2a23d9e
```

Let's split your task into subtasks:

First, specify the `regex`

```
final regex = RegExp('\'.+\'');
```

Next, let's try to find our `target` value with `regex` (assume that we have it all the time to omit nullability case here)

```
final target = regex.stringMatch(string)!;
```

Next, replace the `target` in the original string with some `placeholder`

```
final placeholder = '{@}';
final updatedString = string.replaceAll(regex, placeholder);
```

Next, split `updatedString` into `tokens`

```
final tokens = updatedString.split(RegExp(' '));
```

Next, build our `TextSpan`'s by tokens. If the `token` is a `placeholder` then we replace it with the `target` and needed style

```
final spans = tokens
    .map((e) => e == placeholder
        ? TextSpan(text: target + ' ', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue))
        : TextSpan(text: e + ' '))
    .toList();
```

And last, collect everything together

```
Text.rich(TextSpan(children: spans)))
```

Full code example

```
class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  final String string;

  const Page({Key? key, required this.string}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final regex = RegExp('\'.+\'');
    const placeholder = '{@}';
    final target = regex.stringMatch(string)!;
    final updatedString = string.replaceAll(regex, placeholder);
    final tokens = updatedString.split(RegExp(' '));
    final spans = tokens
        .map((e) => e == placeholder
        ? TextSpan(text: target + ' ', style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue))
        : TextSpan(text: e + ' '))
        .toList();
    
    return Center(child: Text.rich(TextSpan(children: spans)));
  }
}
```

[image]